# how to deploy an application automatically

Tags: winforms, deployment

In the office here we have a startup script that runs on the server which will update via copy/paste the software in house if there's a newer version on the server or not. This was simple, easy and fast to implement.

There is now a problem, many of our users are off-site and they use laptops/tables which don't connect to the domain to run the startup scripts - which means that these have to be manually deployed. This was fine for the one user that I've had for a good while. Now that I've got 10 - it's a no go. I've got to figure out a better solution.

Without developing something homegrown, are there any solutions out there that make auto-deploying/updating easier?

Note: This is a winforms app.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is [ClickOnce](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t71a733d.aspx) an option?

There's a lot to read at the link I am pointing you to, but it's really pretty simple.  You would have to publish the app to a live web server, though.  Something that can be accessed from off the domain.  That could pose some security concerns.  It's one avenue to explore, though.

Comment: I agree - ClickOnce seems to be the best solution. I've used it extensively in an enterprise environment deploying both .NET and legacy apps. Its fantastic!

Is VPN an option for getting your users 'inside' your domain?

Comment: +1 I'm gonna check out that link.
@Dan: Yes and no. We do have a VPN connection but it's only used for admin staff. However, all of the people who VPN also Remote Desktop to a machine/virtual machine... so it doesn't affect them anyway.

Comment: ClickOnce is the best solution.  I've also used it in enterprise development.. really slick.  Automatic updates? A breeze.

Comment: Ok, after implementing and deploying it to all of my users... it's a god send. The local and remote users get their updates, I don't have to worry about anything, just click publish to our FTP. It's really wonderful, and quite easy. My users don't have install privileges either, and it's not needed. Thank you very much David.